# Is there a better way to loop and insert an element in list python

Tags: python-3.x, enumerate

I was trying to insert a blank line in a list of dictionaries, so I used enumerate() to insert the element at the particular index. The issue is the program does not end it keeps executing

r = a list of dictionaries

m = a list of dictionaries

```
bl = {'col0' : "Blank line"}                                                                       
for idx,i in enumerate(r):
   for q in m:
     if q[key] == "value":
         r.insert(idx,bl)
```

Comment: Create a new list instead of appending to the current one

Comment: But  as mentioned above I need to add this "bl" that the particular index that I am getting using enumerate()

Comment: If you iterate through a dictionary and also insert into that dictionary, then you are creating an infinite loop. Aren't you? So you want to think of a different solution. Maybe store it elsewhere and use the new dictionary (or a list)

Comment: Thanks, Joe Ferndz  did the same it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are inserting the element in the original list(**r**). so basically whenever the if condition is true, the list grows and hence loops infinitely. You just need to make a copy of the original list and loop over it. I have provided the sample code for it.

```
import copy
r_copy = copy.deepcopy(r)
bl = {'col0' : "Blank line"}                                                                       
for idx,i in enumerate(r_copy):
   for q in m:
     if q[key] == "value":
         r.insert(idx,bl)
```

Comment: Thanks -Karan Raj  It worked. Actually, I am using the same code twice just the condition is different one is working and the other didn't so I got stuck, it's strange!